# UK visa rejected. No salary deposited in bank account

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I want to travel to UK. I have Thailand passport. Currently working in Malaysia as a domestic worker. My employer want to sponsor me to follow his wife to travel to UK and Paris. but my visa UK visa got rejected.

Based on the refusal, I need to provide a letter of leave from my employer. I can get that letter as he is the one who is sponsoring me

second reason is because I can't provide a bank statement that prove my salary. I did provide them with my bank statement. But I received my salary in cash every month. I am currently working with the same employer for more than 7 years.

Can I provide my payslip to support my income as I only received my monthly salary by CASH. I have no other bank account and all my money is saved somewhere but not under my name.

Can i reapply again and submit the necessary document(leave letter from employer and payslip) and deposit all my previous salary that i received in cash and provide the payslip to justify the large deposit amount ?

please help

[image: Refusal Letter]

Comment: Hello. Can you tell us if your employer wants you to follow his wife to work for her while traveling ?

Comment: hello, basically, I will follow his wife to travel. but I will not work for my employer wife or work with anyone while i am in UK. my employer want to sponsor me to follow her wife to UK as a gift for working with him for so long (more than 5 years). sometimes they bring me go to Korea, Jakarta, Australia as a yearly gift. My real job is taking care of kids. but no kids follow. only adults.

Comment: Seems like your application is on very shaky grounds. Visa is unlikely to be granted.

Comment: thank you very much for all your comment/replies. Currently, I am wondering, I want to reapply, based on the refusal letter, what other document i should provide to support my visa application. I am a genuine visitor. I already bought the plane ticket. I already have my travel plan and accommodation booked. my plan is to go london, then travel to paris. then take a flight back from paris

Comment: Did you already ask and/or get a Schengen visa for your travel to Paris?

Comment: I still have not applied my Schengen visa yet. My appointment for France Visa is tomorrow(15 Jan). Hopefully I will get that visa. And reapply my UK visa again.

Comment: Why is your money in an account but not under your name? Is it in an account under a family member's name or what?